# Trying to get triangle numbers

Tags: java, for-loop

The question is 
"Write a program that duplicates the sample run shown at the bottom , which displays the sum of the first n integers for each value of n from 1 to 10. As the output suggests, these numbers can be arranged to form a triangle and are therefore called triangle numbers
1 = 1 
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 2 + 3 = 6
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 21
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 = 36
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 45
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 55"

I am able to output 1 2 3 4 5... to 10, but I just can't figure out how to get it to look like the triangle above and make it add the next consecutive number.  I'm assuming that I am missing something very obvious.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class prob3
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int n = 1; n <= 10; n++) {
            for (int i = n; i <= n; i++){

            System.out.println(n);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I suppose the numbers are steaming down vertically as opposed to horizontally broken by lines? Look carefully at your print statement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you print **whole** lines just with those numbers.
You print:

1

2

3

But you need something like

1=1

1+2=3

Instead, you need to **accumulate** the content to be printed, like:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = n; i <= n; i++) {
  builder.append(n);
  builder.append("+");...
  System.out.println(builder.toString() + "=" + sum);
}
```

The above is just meant to to get you going; as there are still some things missing that you will have to work with:

A) figuring how to use the StringBuilder to "remember" that part of the previous line that you can *reuse*!

B) computation of overall sum is missing (as it is in your code, too!)

Comment: I am on my way to class now so I need to try this later.  I've never used string builder before; and I kept trying the word "total" instead of sum which kept giving me an error so that was just silly!  When I get back home, I will try this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Split the handling of each row into a helper method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        printRow(i);
    }
}

/**
 * Print one row.
 * 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = sum
 * @param n the max for this row
 */
private static void printRow(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // 1 through n-1
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        // TODO - update the sum
        // TODO - update sb with the number and plus
    }

    // final number n
    // TODO - update the sum
    // TODO - update the sb with the final number, equals, and sum

    // display
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```